# How to add self-hosted fonts in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, material-ui

I'm trying to add a custom font in my web project, using material-ui createMuiTheme function and I'm following the given example: [self hosted font material ui example](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#self-hosted-fonts).

But as much as i try i can't implement the expected font.
And when I log the theme constant i see that the *Raleway* font that I'm trying to implement is not in the theme:

[image: Typography without Raleway font]

I'm using react 16.5.2, material-ui 4.3.1 and webpack. And the font is a ttf file.

My webpack config adds the following rule to load the font:

**./webpack.config.js**

```js
{
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Following the peviously mentioned example, I have an other file exporting the specific font as a const:

**./src/fonts/index.js**

```js
import RalewayWoff2 from './Raleway-Regular.ttf';

export const raleway = {
  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontDisplay: 'swap',
  fontWeight: 400,
  src: `
    local('Raleway'),
    local('Raleway-Regular'),
    url(${RalewayWoff2}) format('woff2')
  `,
  unicodeRange: 'U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF',
};
```

And in my index.js I'm implementing the createMuiTheme like this:

**./src/index.js**

```js
import * as fonts from './fonts';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        typography: {
          fontFamily: 'Raleway, Arial',
        },
        overrides: {
          MuiCssBaseline: {
            '@global': {
              '@font-face': [fonts.raleway],
            },
          },
        },
    }
});

render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme = { theme }>
                <App />
            </MuiThemeProvider>, 
        </Router>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks mostly correct but this post is referencing a truetype font while giving it the format of "woff2"... that is not correct. Other than that this should probably work.